# Python Check if element exists in SQLite result

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to see if the username inputted by the user already exists on my database. Currently I am able to create usernames that have already been taken. This is my current code (newUser is a string):

```
with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            taken = cursor.execute('SELECT username FROM users')
            takenUsers = taken.fetchall()
            conn.commit()

if newUser in takenUsers:
            session['error'] = 'Username already taken'
            return redirect('/error')
```

I am not sure why it doesn't work; isn't takenUsers a tuple since I used fetchall()?
Alternatively I want to check if the username a user inputs in the login page actually exists. This code does not work and returns a 404 error, rather than an error that I have created:

```
with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as conn:
            conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            rows = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?',
                                (username,))
            conn.commit()
        
rows = rows.fetchall()
# Check for valid username/password
if not rows or not check_password_hash(rows[0]['hash'], password):
            session['error'] = 'Invalid username and/or password'
            return redirect('error.html')
```

Comment: Hello, are you sure about the path of your error page?

Comment: @Handler Redirection to my error page works. For example if I try to sign up with a username that is too long, it will redirect with the correct error message.

Comment: You should print takenUsers so you can see what it returns (hint: it's not a tuple of strings).

Comment: @thebjorn Serious question, how do you print something when you're using flask? (Without rendering the webpage with the values of course)

Comment: In dev, prints should go to the terminal where you're running the dev server. In production you should probably set up logging: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/logging/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out using fetchall returns a list of tuples, so I was able to find the string like this:

```
for item in takenUsers:
            if item[0] == newUser:
                session['error'] = 'Username already taken'
                return redirect('/error')
```